# How can I insert a list of numbers into a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert a list of comment IDs into a column `liked_comments`.

For example if a user likes comments with IDs `72`, `839`, `37`, then they will be stored in there.

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['id']); // a number posted using ajax from another file
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_SESSION['username']);

if (!empty($_POST) && isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE users SET liked_comments=liked_comments+$id WHERE username='$username'");
}
```

At the moment this just adds the IDs as though they were numbers rather than strings, but I need it to be `71,789,173` or `71 789 173` separated by a space or comma. Adding `+' '+` or `+','+` didn't seem to work.

Comment: My favorite list of liked_comments is **`'2,3,banana,5,sqrt(49)'`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot concatenate using `+` in mysql, you have to use [concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) like

```
$Query = "UPDATE users SET liked_comments=concat(liked_comments, ',', '$id') WHERE username='$username'";
```

Also, Instead of storing comma separated values in column, you can move comments part to separated table, where each row contain `PostID` and `UserID`, that would be much neater and flexible.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to store arrays inside the database. For example; if we have this array:

`$liked_comments_array = array(71, 789, 173);`

You can store it in the array like so:

```
$liked_comments_array = serialize($liked_comments_array);
// now insert this into the database
```

Then when you fetch this array from the database, simply unserialize it like so:

`$liked_array_comments = unserialize($field_from_database);`

Comment: I don't think it's good solution, think about if OP needs to get comments user wise, he must need to get results in php and unserialize and compare